# How do I navigate back to the project page from a search in a repo on Github?

Tags: github

For example, given I am searching within a repository:

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acastwide%2Fsolargraph+formatter&type=code

How do I navigate to its project page? (the one at: https://github.com/castwide/solargraph )

I.e. can I click somewhere or press a key to navigate to the project page?

I discovered I can delete the characters of my search query and search again but that sounds more like a workaround or hack instead of intended UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This had me confused for a while as well, but there is a way back to the project from the search interface. It's just not very obvious and a pretty poor piece of UI design in my humble opinion.

At the top of the search results, just after the number of files retrieved the project name is shown, if you click this is will take you back to the project - not much use if, as in this example, you have scrolled through 200+ results and it's now off the page but that's the only way I have found:

[image: screenshot of Github search result showing where project name can be clicked]

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful. I also created a bookmarklet to solve this issue:

```javascript
javascript:(function(){var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); var qParam = urlParams.get('q'); var repoMatch = /repo:([^ ]+)/.exec(qParam); if(repoMatch){var repo = repoMatch[1]; window.location.href="https://github.com/"+repo;}})();
```